# how to duplicate ListViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, mvvm

I want to know if there is a possibility to have 2 similar listView structures, using the properties Binding. So, I have a ListView which contains different Items with different sizes. Beside it, I want to create another listView with other items, but the size of each Item will be the same as the size of the according item in the first ListView.

Example:

The size of the Item 1 of the 1st ListView = The size of the Item 1 of the 2nd ListView

The size of the Item 2 of the 1st ListView = The size of the Item 2 of the 2nd ListView

...

...

The size of the Item x of the 1st ListView = The size of the Item x of the 2nd ListView

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try to achieve this by first overriding the item template in ListView1 to set the height of each item via a multi-binding. That would bind to the ListView1 data context, the current item and the second list control. You would then create a multi-converter for this binding which would accept these values from the multi-binding, determine the index of the item in the ListView1 item list and then look up that element in ListView2 to get its ActualHeight. Having said all this I would really, REALLY think hard about whether there's a better way to achieve what you're trying to accomplish because this probably won't work with virtualization and there may be performance implications doing the initial index into the first list for every element (although I've solved that particular problem in the past by also passing in a Dictionary to do the mapping in O(1) time).